# Angular 2 upgradeNg1Component not working - unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I'm trying to create a simple Angular 1 + 2 hybrid application in TypeScript using the component directive pattern as described here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#using-angular-1-component-directives-from-angular-2-code

I got it working with the regular directive declaration, but I can't get it to work with the component directive.

Just to contextualize: I'm actually creating a new Angular 2 application, but I need a component that hasn't been converted yet, called Formly, so I'm thinking about using the Angular 1 version in the meantime.

The full code is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/J5rK48?p=preview

I created a component directive following the heroDetail sample on the guide:

```
export const tstv1 = {
  template: `<a>Angular 1: {{value}}</a><br/>`,
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.value = 'Angular 1';
  }
};
```

Then I tried to use it by upgrading the component:

```
const tstv1 = upgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Component('tstv1')
```

However this throws an error:

> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tstv1DirectiveProvider <- tstv1Directive
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.1/$injector/unpr?>p0=tstv1DirectiveProvider%20%3C-%20tstv1Directive

What am I doing wrong?

Also, the examples don't have a import statement for the component directive. Should I add it or not? I have tried both and it doesn't work either way. If there isn't a import, how would Angular know where to get the directive from?

I tried it like this:

```
import {tstv1} from 'src/tstv1/tstv1.component'
```

Like I said I got it working using a regular directive:

```
app.directive('tstv1directive', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: '?ngModel',
            template: '<a>Inside directive: {{value}}</a>',
            controller: function($scope) {
              $scope.value = "Works!"
            }
        }
    }))
```

and I can upgrade and use it just fine:

```
upgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Component('tstv1directive')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the working one: https://plnkr.co/edit/nAiqX2w4ENkYd6Z8db7M?p=preview

The way you 'create' the component directive was actually just create an object, you have to register it as a component.

see main.ts

```
app.component('tstv1', tstv1);
```

and you have to import the tstv1 object as well in main.ts

after that, just downgrade it like the one you did with the regular directive.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

I just find it odd that this isn't documented on the official upgrade guide.

Comment: well, the guide and all other examples that can be found are piece and pieces. that's why I am currently working on my blog (http://www.waynehong.com/) to put everything together and show them in complete examples. I just started it, so there are only few posts at the moment, will come to upgrade part soon.